# Capitals for a city nickname?

Tags: capitalization, nicknames

Say we pick a city, NotLondon. Now assign a nickname, "NotLondon, **the city of tears**", tears being a metaphor for rain. Should these be capitalized? Should the word 'the' be capitalized? I think it counts as a proper noun, in which case the answer would be yes.

New York: **the Big Apple** seems obvious to me (although it seems 'the' is not part of the nick name as it is not capitalized), but when using words to describe a city rather than naming it (the city **of tears**), I'm not so sure. The description *is* its nickname.

English is not my native tongue, so please be explicit with grammar references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [A word or group of words {such as “Noah Webster,” “Kentucky,” or “U.S. Congress”} that is the name of a particular person, place, or thing and that usually begins with a capital letter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proper%20noun)

is a proper noun. --Merriam-Webster Dictionary.

That would include nicknames.

Articles preceding such are not capitalized unless they begin a sentence, following the Chicago Manual of Style, 16th Edition:

> the Eternal City
>   the Windy City

If an expression is used merely to describe a city, they would not generally be capitalized in prose or under "sentence style".

Comment: Your examples helped illustrate it quite well. My initial conclusion is correct then; NotLondon, the City of Tears, by virtue of being a proper noun despite being its description as well depending on the use in a sentence.

Comment: If it's a description, no. It gets tricky if you *think* of it as a nickname. Even if it's not recognized as one by others, I think it gets capitalized. If I ddcided to call you *Vegetable Head,* then that's my name for you, and it's a proper noun.